# Private Key Update at TFS Build Server

Tags: tfs, build, private-key

I am facing signing issue once i try to build the project from TFS build Definition. Few Days back Private key .pfx was got expired & dll's are not getting digitally signed through build tempplate. Getting this error.

SignTool Error: The signer's certificate is not valid for signing.
SignTool Error: An error occurred while attempting to sign:
Code Signing failed for DLL Path..

Although i have received new private key & have installed this at build server but still getting error. however through command line i can do digitally sign. But using build definition at build server it's failing & build is getting partially succeeded.
Can anyone help me to tell about the location at build server where we can update the private key so that it's get signed through build template.

Please suggest your thoughts.

Thanks,

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Can you show the build definition you're using and the output log files?

Comment: Thanks Mate..Issue is resolved Actually there was some issue in build template custom assemblies. We re-build again & it worked well.